# Warning: Creating default object from empty value Undefined property: stdClass::$id

Tags: php, json

tengo un json

```
 {
"id": 727,
"parent_id": 0,
"number": "727",
"shipping": {
  "first_name": "John",
  "last_name": "Doe",
"cart_hash": "",
"meta_data": [
  {
    "id": 13106,
    "key": "_download_permissions_granted",
    "value": "yes"
  },
  {
    "id": 13109,
    "key": "_order_stock_reduced",
    "value": "yes"
  }
],
"line_items": [
  {
    "id": 315,
    "name": "Woo Single #1",
    "product_id": 93,
    "variation_id": 0,
    "quantity": 2,
    "tax_class": "",
    "subtotal": "6.00",
    "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
    "total": "6.00",
    "total_tax": "0.45",
    "taxes": [
      {
        "id": 75,
        "total": "0.45",
        "subtotal": "0.45"
      }
    ],
    "meta_data": [],
    "sku": "",
    "price": 3
  }
```

Estoy tratando de acceder a line_items -> id, ¿Como puedo hacerlo?
He probado con el siguiente codigo en php

```
foreach($products8 as $pros->line_items){
$idatributo8 = $pros->id; //Id del producto principal
echo $idatributo8;}
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Warning: Creating default object from empty value
> Undefined property: stdClass::$id
> He probado utilizando json_decode pero el resultado es el mismo, ¿Alguien me puede ayudar? de ante mano muchas gracias!

Comment: puedes llamar un ajax para que cargues los datos en esos momentos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para que el json que muestras tenga una estructura válida, considera que debería estar así:

```
        [{
            "id": 727,
            "parent_id": 0,
            "number": "727",
            "shipping": {
                "first_name": "John",
                "last_name": "Doe",
                "cart_hash": "",
                "meta_data": [{
                        "id": 13106,
                        "key": "_download_permissions_granted",
                        "value": "yes"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": 13109,
                        "key": "_order_stock_reduced",
                        "value": "yes"
                    }
                ],
                "line_items": [{
                    "id": 315,
                    "name": "Woo Single #1",
                    "product_id": 93,
                    "variation_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "tax_class": "",
                    "subtotal": "6.00",
                    "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
                    "total": "6.00",
                    "total_tax": "0.45",
                    "taxes": [{
                        "id": 75,
                        "total": "0.45",
                        "subtotal": "0.45"
                    }],
                    "meta_data": [],
                    "sku": "",
                    "price": 3
                }]
            }
        }]
```

Posterior, debes realizar lo siguiente:

- Usa la función [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) para realizar la decodificación de la cadena o string de json y lo asignas a una variable de esta forma:

  ```
    $cadenaDatos = json_decode($products8);
  ```
- Ahora para el proceso de interación, realizar esto:

  ```
    foreach($products8 as $pros->line_items){
  ```

Es incorrecto, desde el momento que la clave `line_items` no esta en el *primer nivel por asi decirlo de tu json*, sino que esta o pertenece como clave de `shipping`

- Entonces la iteración alcanza con realizarla de la siguiente manera:

  ```
    foreach ($products8 as $producto) {
        .........................
    }
  ```
- Posterior, si dentro del ciclo hacemos esto:

  ```
    print_r($producto->shipping->line_items);
  ```

Verás esto como salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 315
            [name] => Woo Single #1
            [product_id] => 93
            [variation_id] => 0
            [quantity] => 2
            [tax_class] => 
            [subtotal] => 6.00
            [subtotal_tax] => 0.45
            [total] => 6.00
            [total_tax] => 0.45
            [taxes] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 75
                            [total] => 0.45
                            [subtotal] => 0.45
                        )

                )

            [meta_data] => Array
                (
                )

            [sku] => 
            [price] => 3
        )

)
```

Estamos obteniendo un *array de objetos* por lo que de manera inicial podemos indicar el índice en el cual se encuentra el objeto el que deseamos acceder y posterior la clave de la cual queremos imprimir su valor de esta forma:

```
print_r($producto->shipping->line_items[0]->id);
```

Tu código completo entonces sería:

```
$products8 = '
              [{
                "id": 727,
                "parent_id": 0,
                "number": "727",
                "shipping": {
                  "first_name": "John",
                  "last_name": "Doe",
                  "cart_hash": "",
                  "meta_data": [{
                      "id": 13106,
                      "key": "_download_permissions_granted",
                      "value": "yes"
                    },
                    {
                      "id": 13109,
                      "key": "_order_stock_reduced",
                      "value": "yes"
                    }
                  ],
                  "line_items": [{
                    "id": 315,
                    "name": "Woo Single #1",
                    "product_id": 93,
                    "variation_id": 0,
                    "quantity": 2,
                    "tax_class": "",
                    "subtotal": "6.00",
                    "subtotal_tax": "0.45",
                    "total": "6.00",
                    "total_tax": "0.45",
                    "taxes": [{
                      "id": 75,
                      "total": "0.45",
                      "subtotal": "0.45"
                    }],
                    "meta_data": [],
                    "sku": "",
                    "price": 3
                  }]
                }
              }]
         ';
        
$cadenaDatos = json_decode($products8);
        
        
foreach ($cadenaDatos as $producto) {
   print_r($producto->shipping->line_items[0]->id);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! me ha funcionado perfectamente el código, de ante mano mil gracias BetaM ;)

Comment: @EstuardoValenzuela no hay de que, si te sirvió considera que puedes marcarla como aceptada