# ¿Cómo solucionar error de Argumento No Valido para Foreach() en PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Actualice la version de mi php de 7.3 a 7.4 y me empezo a lanzar los errores de "Argumento No Valido", he estado leyendo, pero aun asi no logro identificar el error,

Este es mi codigo:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
set_time_limit(0);
require('mysqli.php');
$data = file_get_contents('responseimg.json');
$datas = json_decode($data);
ExecuteNonQuery("TRUNCATE TABLE db_imagenes;");
foreach($datas as $q) {
  if(count($q) > 0) {
    foreach($q as $r) {
            $imagenEnBase64 = $r->imagen;
            $upload_path = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]. '/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/';
            $decoded = base64_decode($imagenEnBase64);
            $filename = $r->articulo.'.png';
            $hashed_filename = md5($filename . microtime()) . '_' . $filename;
            $salida = $upload_path . $hashed_filename;
            $image_upload = file_put_contents($upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded);
            $salidas = "https://[CLIENT_URL]/wp-content/uploads/2020/11/" .$hashed_filename;
            $salida_src = "2020/11/" .$hashed_filename;

        ExecuteNonQuery("INSERT INTO db_imagenes (art_codigo, imagenes, imagenes_src, imagenes_name) VALUES ('*?*', '*?*', '*?*', '*?*');", array(
          $r->articulo,
          $salidas,
          $salida_src,
          $hashed_filename,
        ));
    }
  }
}
echo '{

     "Response": "Imagenes Importadas Con Exito"

}';
?>
    <script>
        location.href = 'woocommerce-imagen-2.php';
    </script>
```

Un ejemplo de los datos dentro del json

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "articulo": 6271,
      "imagen": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI…AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEH//Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

En otros archivos no tienen ningun problema, solo en este archivo,

Alguna sugerencia?

Gracias!

Comment: Qué tiene `$datas`? Puedes colocar en la pregunta un ejemplo?

Comment: Dudo que el problema sea por la versión de PHP, tal vez hay error en el archivo donde obtienes los datos, agrega `var_dump($datas);` antes y después de convertir a _JSON_ para verificar

Comment: @Bicho es una imagen en cadena Base64

Comment: Solo debe ser un foreach del nodo `items`

Answer (score 1):

Similar a lo que ya respondí [en esta otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/415385/warning-creating-default-object-from-empty-value-undefined-property-stdclass/415400?noredirect=1#comment742688_415400) el tema viene de como estás *tratando* a la data que intentas iterar, entonces para resumir:

- Debes antes de iterar, usar la función `json_decode` y pasarle como argumento a *$datas*

  ```
  $datos = json_decode($datas);
  ```
- Una vez hecho lo anterior, notarás que si dentro del ciclo haces esto:

  ```
  foreach ($datos as $dato) {
      print_r($dato);
  }
  ```

Te dará una salida como esta:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [articulo] => 6271
            [imagen] => /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI…AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEH//Z
        )

)
```

Bien ahi mismo puedes ver que tienes un *array de objetos*, entonces puedes indicar **en este caso el índice de objeto deseado** de esta forma:

```
print_r($dato[0]);
```

Lo cual te da acceso a las propiedades y objetos del mismo:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [articulo] => 6271
    [imagen] => /9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI…AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEH//Z
)
```

Luego entonces ahora si puedes usar de forma válida la sintaxis de: **`$variable->clave`** quedando así:

```
foreach ($datos as $dato) {
    echo $dato[0]->articulo;
    echo $dato[0]->imagen;
}
```

O bien si el *array* contiene mas de un objeto, podemos iterar 2 veces y no depender de señalar directamente el índice de cada uno de ellos, así:

```
$datas = '
            {
                "items": [
                            {
                                "articulo": 6271,
                                "imagen": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI…AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEH//Z"
                            },
                            {
                                "articulo": 6272,
                                "imagen": "/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI…AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEH//Z"
                            }
                         ]
            }
        ';
        

$datos = json_decode($datas);

foreach ($datos as $dato) {
    foreach ($dato as $grupoDatos) {
        echo $grupoDatos->articulo.PHP_EOL;
        echo $grupoDatos->imagen.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

Con una salida así:

```
6271
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI…AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEH//Z
6272
/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEASABI…AQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEH//Z
```

- Acá puedes leer sobre la clase stándar [**`stdClass`**](https://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.classes.php#reserved.classes.standard)

Comment: Me parece correcta la formula, y está bien como cumple la función, pero el inconveniente es que son más de 6210 artículos o imágenes, la cuales se guardan dentro del archivo responseimg.json

El código funciona bien cuando se trata de pocas cadenas, pero al llegar a ese numero, ya me indica el error de "Argumento Invalido para foreach()"